# How to make custom UIBarButtonItem with image and label?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I would like to make a custom UIBarButtonItem that contains both image and text, something like this:

[image]

I tried subclassing UIBarButtonItem and overriding this method:

```
- (UIView *)customView
{
    if (!self.storedView) {

        UIView *temp = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 44)];
        UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:self.image];
        tempImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.image.size.width, self.image.size.height);
        UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(44, 0, 100, 44)];
        tempLabel.text = @"text";
        [temp addSubview:tempImageView];
        [temp addSubview:tempLabel];
        self.storedView = temp;
    }
    return self.storedView;
}
```

And I use it like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *left = [[LeftItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Settings" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(settingsPressed)];
left.title = @"Settings";
left.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = left;
```

But using this I only get the image, but not label. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)];
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, 5, 50, 20)];
[label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:13]];
[label setText:title];
label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button addSubview:label];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can set the image to the buttons background image property, and that removes the need to add a label, because you can use the buttons label instead.

Comment: Any suggestions how I would accomplish this in Interface Builder? I hate having parts of the UI in code and parts in IB.

Comment: @oarfish write everything in code - problem solved :D That's most senior devs do it.

Comment: Unable to set tintColor to button with this approach any thoughts on setting tintColor?

Answer (score 23):

You can add a custom view to the `UIBarButtonItem`.

In iOS 7, there is a new buttonType called `UIButtonTypeSystem` for `UIButton` which serve your purpose.
Try this,

```
UIView* leftButtonView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 110, 50)];

UIButton* leftButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
leftButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
leftButton.frame = leftButtonView.frame;
[leftButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:<YourImageName>] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[leftButton setTitle:@"YourTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
leftButton.tintColor = [UIColor redColor]; //Your desired color.
leftButton.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
leftButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(<YourTargetMethod>) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[leftButtonView addSubview:leftButton];

UIBarButtonItem* leftBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:leftButtonView];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;
```

Updated **Swift** code,

```
let leftButtonView = UIView.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 110, height: 50))

let leftButton = UIButton.init(type: .system)
leftButton.backgroundColor = .clear
leftButton.frame = leftButtonView.frame
leftButton.setImage(UIImage.init(imageLiteralResourceName: <YourImageName>), for: .normal)
leftButton.setTitle("YourTitle", for: .normal)
leftButton.tintColor = .red //Your desired color.
leftButton.autoresizesSubviews = true
leftButton.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth , .flexibleHeight]
leftButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(<YourTargetMethod>), for: .touchUpInside)
leftButtonView.addSubview(leftButton)

let leftBarButton = UIBarButtonItem.init(customView: leftButtonView)
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton
```

Comment: The question is, what should be the image's dimensions to look exactly like the native back image? (I want to create my own custom back button so I can control its events...)

Comment: This works when assign with: "self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftBarButton;" but it doesnt when assign it to UIBarbuttonItem like "self.boto_icona_client = leftBarButton;" any idea why?

Answer (score 14):

If your BarButtonItem is in Storyboard, you can drag another Button into BarButtonItem, so there will be a Button inside the BarButtonItem, you can add both image and label to the button.

Comment: Confirmed that this is working in both iOS7 and iOS8.

Comment: You cannot adjust the height of BarButtonItems lower than 44p in Storyboard in iOS13. Must be done programmatically.

Answer (score 12):

a SWIFT version

```
    let button =  UIButton(type: .Custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_right"), forState: .Normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 31)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 32, 1, -32)//move image to the right
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(3, 5, 50, 20))
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 16)
    label.text = "title"
    label.textAlignment = .Center
    label.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    label.backgroundColor =   UIColor.clearColor()
    button.addSubview(label)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```

Answer (score 5):

Using UIButton as custom view inside your UIBarButtonItem. You can create UIButton however you want, including with an image and text, using `-setImage:forState:` and `-setTitle:forState:`

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:@"Settings" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* barButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButtonItem;
```

this can be done using interface builder just by dragging a UIButton to the left bar button slot on a navigation bar.

Answer (score 4):

The problem with the accepted answer is that the `UIBarButtonItem` text does not change when highlighted.  The code below will display text plus an image.  The `UIEdgeInsetsMake` moves the text to the left and the image to the right.

```
UIButton *button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(myButtonEvent:) 
             forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 53, 32)];

[button setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] 
                 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor] 
                 forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
button.titleEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, -20, 2, 20);
button.titleLabel.font = font;
button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageName"];
[button setImage:image 
        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 32, 1, -32);
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Answer (score 3):

I posted answer that handles tint colour and image simmilar to normal uibarbuttonitem here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/28348461/925135

Answer (score 3):

Another approach with NSAttributedString:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Button Text"];
NSTextAttachment *textAttachment = [[NSTextAttachment alloc] init];
textAttachment.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"buttonImage"];
textAttachment.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -3, textAttachment.image.size.width, textAttachment.image.size.height); //the origin y value depends on the size of the image to get a perfect fit
NSAttributedString *attrStringWithImage = [NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:textAttachment];
[attributedString replaceCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) withAttributedString:attrStringWithImage]; // Adding the image at the beginning
[customButton setAttributedTitle:attributedString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton sizeToFit];
[customButton addTarget:self action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's my solution based on previous answers. May be will be helpful.

```
extension UIBarButtonItem {
    static func button(image: UIImage, title: String, target: Any, action: Selector) -> UIBarButtonItem {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
        button.setTitle(title, for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        return UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    }
}
```

Comment: how can set title left side of image instead of right side?

Answer (score 2):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIImage *backgroundSelected = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon_selected.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(ButtonTapped:event:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; //adding action
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setBackgroundImage:backgroundSelected forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,0,35,35);
```

then make that button as your custom barbutton

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the updated version of ripegooseberry's answer for Swift 3

```
    let button =  UIButton(type: .custom)
    button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_right"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("buttonAction")), for: .touchUpInside)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 53, height: 31)
    button.imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-1, 32, 1, -32)//move image to the right
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 3, y: 5, width: 50, height: 20))
    label.font = UIFont(name: "Arial-BoldMT", size: 16)
    label.text = "title"
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.textColor = UIColor.white
    label.backgroundColor =   UIColor.clear
    button.addSubview(label)
    let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = barButton
```