# Add labels to Toolbar items in XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, toolbar

I am using swift with xcode. I am having trouble putting a label underneath an image for a toolbar item. Either it only allows a label or only an image. I want to do something like this

[Example of toolbar item](http://www.imagehousing.com/image/1222596)

But i am not able to do that through xcode

Comment: Have you checked this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200129/ios-7-barbuttonitem-with-image-and-title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised i could use a TabViewController for scenarios like this