# In iOS7, UIBarButtonItems do not respect bold "Done" styling when using UIAppearance proxy

Tags: ios, uikit, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uiappearance

In iOS7, by default UIBarButtonItem uses a Helvetica regular weight font for style UIBarButtonItemStylePlain and a bold weight for UIBarButtonItemStyleDone.

My app uses custom fonts, and I'm using a UIAppearance proxy to achieve this:

```
appearance = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"ProximaNova-Regular" size:18.0]};
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:appearance
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

The trouble is, the appearance proxy makes the Plain and Done styled buttons the regular weight font I specified above.

Any ideas how I could get UIBarButtonItem to use different custom font weights depending on the style?

Comment: Hey Mark, I know this is a long overdue answer but did you try subclassing the UIBarButtonItem and adding a custom view? Have a look at this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844681/how-to-make-custom-uibarbuttonitem-with-image-and-label. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it is late answer, but it can be helpful for somebody:

```
   UIBarButtonItem *customBarButton =
        [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CustomTitle", @"This button appears in my smexy ViewController's naviagtion bar")
                                         style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                        target:self
                                        action:@selector(customButtonDidClick:)];

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:14.0f],
                                 NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]}; // here you can add some other keys (especially in iOS 7) to personalize your button title more 

    [customBarButton setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:customBarButton];
```

Edited: thanks for detection of my typo :-)

Comment: Thanks @Neru! That works. FYI: There's a missing @ in front of the font string.

Comment: Neither to I, it's not using the appearance proxy.... Any way to do it via the appearance proxy?