# How to make custom right UIBarButtonItem with image and label?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I actually found this same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844681/how-to-make-custom-uibarbuttonitem-with-image-and-label) but for obj.c so with that I managed to do this:

```
trashNavButton = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.Custom) as! UIButton
        trashNavButton.addTarget(self, action: "trashItemClicked", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
trashNavButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 32))
trashNavButton.setTitle("\(trashCount)", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
trashNavButton.setTitleColor(UIColor(red: 229.0/255.0, green: 57.0/255.0, blue: 53.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
trashNavButton.titleLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
trashNavButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "trashButton"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
rightBarButton.customView = trashNavButton
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

What I'm trying to do is to have a button on the right at the navigation bar, and I want that button to also have a label on it's left (you can see a great example on the question I mentioned above), and well this code works very well with the exception that the image is on the left and the label on the right and I want it to be the other way around, I'll appreciate your help :)

Comment: Pay attention to custom View on uibarbuttonitem. Like this: self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: yourCustomView) it seems will help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just as an example

[image]

```
let containView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,70, 40))

let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 40))
label.text = "Right"
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Center

containView.addSubview(label)

let imageview = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(50, 10, 20, 20))
imageview.image = UIImage(named: "memoAccess")
imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill
containView.addSubview(imageview)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: containView)
```

Comment: How can I make the label to align to the right? The text will be a number that can change

Comment: Right thanks, you know how to make it works like a button? changing the color while highlighted and also adding an action to it