# Add tab bar in tableview controller storyboard

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I am in a need to show same style like a tab bar controller provide(button with image). But the need is i need to implement the tab bar on the tableview controller.

How should i suppose to do this ?

i want to add three buttons on the bottom of tableview controller like the tab bar controller.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed question on what you want to achieve? Maybe add an image.

Comment: basically i want to add three buttons on the bottom of tableview controller like the tab bar controller.

Comment: You can do that by adding three buttons in the  bottom of your tableview controller.

Comment: it is a tableview controller , this is what the problem is , when ever i add anything it was directly added to tableview

Comment: I think Taking `tableview` inside a `viewcontroller` will be the best solution for you, then you can easily add three `buttons` at the bottom of your `viewcontroller` by decreasing the height of your `tableView`.

Comment: yes its a good idea but i'm working on an already written code and previous developer used the tableview controller.

Answer (score 2):

Click on your tableview controller, then at the top click on editor then Embed in and select Tab bar controller, or if you don't want to embed your controller into a tab bar, drag and drop a bar button item.

[image: Bar button]

Comment: drag and drop a bar button added the button in the tableview. I need button at the bottom on view

Comment: @ParvBhasker check the image I added to the answer.. is that what you want or am I misunderstanding your question

Comment: yes, but i have to show image above the button text too. and i guess bar button can show either the image or the text.

Comment: @ParvBhasker or try this ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844681/how-to-make-custom-uibarbuttonitem-with-image-and-label

Comment: i just used the seperate tab bar on uiview controller to resolve the issue