# iOS right bar button background image overlap with title on ios11

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigationbar, ios11

I am facing issue in margin of right bar button item title.
From iOS11 background image is overlapped means it is not properly right aligned.

It was working pretty good till iOS 10.

Code snippet:

```
UIBarButtonItem *rightItem = self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem;

    [rightItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAVIGATION_NEXT_BUTTON_DISABLED_iOS7]
                             forState:UIControlStateDisabled
                           barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    [rightItem setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:IMAGE_NAVIGATION_NEXT_BUTTON_iOS7]
                         forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];

    rightItem.title = @"Next";
```

[image]

Before iOS11 it was working like this

[image]

Comment: try with `setImage` instead of `setBackgroundImage`

Comment: see this for e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18844681/how-to-make-custom-uibarbuttonitem-with-image-and-label

Comment: If i set image then title is not showing @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: can you update the question

Comment: what update you require in this. my question is that earlier we used to just set background image as a forward icon (Enable and disable) and then set title. it was working fine but now on iOS 11 it is giving overlapping issue. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Can we align uibarbutton background image to right side or just give padding to right barbutton

Comment: try with `imageEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-2, -20, 2, 20);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154982/discussion-between-ashish-agrawal-and-anbu-karthik).